# Bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Tags: android

I am passing my image into xml,by resize my image size using:

```
scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bp, h, w, true);
    imgV.setImageBitmap(scaled);
```

but am getting bitmap size exceeds Vm budget.

> 04-30 18:36:16.552:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7164): FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main 04-30 18:36:16.552:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7164):
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap
>   size exceeds VM budget 04-30
>   18:36:16.552:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7164):     at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native
>   Method) 04-30 18:36:16.552:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7164):     at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:460)
>   04-30 18:36:16.552:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7164):     at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:525)
>   04-30 18:36:16.552:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7164):     at
>   com.webrich.bachflower.TopicController.getImageBitmap(TopicController.java:103)
>   04-30 18:36:16.552:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7164):     at
>   com.webrich.bachflower.TopicController.onCreate(TopicController.java:73)
>   04-30 18:36:16.552:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7164):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   04-30 18:36:16.552:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7164):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
>   04-30 18:36:16.552:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7164):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
>   04-30 18:36:16.552:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7164):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>   04-30 18:36:16.552:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7164):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
>   04-30 18:36:16.552:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7164):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   04-30 18:36:16.552:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7164):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   04-30 18:36:16.552:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7164):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
>   04-30 18:36:16.552:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7164):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
>   Method) 04-30 18:36:16.552:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7164):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   04-30 18:36:16.552:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7164):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   04-30 18:36:16.552:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7164):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>   04-30 18:36:16.552:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7164):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
>   Method) 04-30 18:36:16.602:
>   WARN/ActivityManager(63):   Force
>   finishing activity
>   com.webrich.bachflower/.TopicController
>   04-30 18:36:17.132:
>   WARN/ActivityManager(63): Activity
>   pause timeout for
>   HistoryRecord{407ff648
>   com.webrich.bachflower/.TopicController}
>   04-30 18:36:19.762:
>   DEBUG/SntpClient(63): request time
>   failed: java.net.SocketException:
>   Address family not supported by
>   protocol 04-30 18:36:20.212:
>   INFO/Process(7164): Sending signal.
>   PID: 7164 SIG: 9 04-30 18:36:20.302:
>   INFO/ActivityManager(63): Process
>   com.webrich.bachflower (pid 7164) has
>   died. 04-30 18:36:20.302:
>   INFO/WindowManager(63): WIN DEATH:
>   Window{407e6b88
>   com.webrich.bachflower/com.webrich.bachflower.FlowerController
>   paused=false} 04-30 18:36:20.362:
>   ERROR/InputDispatcher(63): channel
>   '407fcdb8
>   com.webrich.bachflower/com.webrich.bachflower.Topics
>   (server)' ~ Consumer closed input
>   channel or an error occurred. 
>   events=0x8 04-30 18:36:20.362:
>   ERROR/InputDispatcher(63): channel
>   '407fcdb8
>   com.webrich.bachflower/com.webrich.bachflower.Topics
>   (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably
>   broken and will be disposed! 04-30
>   18:36:20.412: INFO/WindowManager(63):
>   WIN DEATH: Window{407fcdb8
>   com.webrich.bachflower/com.webrich.bachflower.Topics
>   paused=false} 04-30 18:36:20.882:
>   WARN/InputManagerService(63): Got
>   RemoteException sending
>   setActive(false) notification to pid
>   7164 uid 10034

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this not a duplicate of this question:
[Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue)

In particular, the answer you are looking for is (#comment link):
[Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue/823966#823966)

Comment: Do exactly what the #comment "private Bitmap decodeFile() {...}" says. I have used this code and dealt with files far in excess of what can be held in-memory.